# How to retrieve the minimum of multi average like this min(avg(salary)) by Aggregate SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, aggregate

I'm using SQL Server and trying to retrieve the minimum of multi averages of salaries in or group by their departments.

I can retrieve the salary's averages of all departments by (group by) by using this query:

```
select d.Dname, avg(e.salary) as averagr_salary
from Employee e, Departments d
where d.Dnum = e.dno
group by e.Dno,d.Dname
```

The results of data like that (the Department_Name and the average_salary):

```
name  avg
----------
DP1   139
DP2  1050
DP3  1250
```

I want to retrieve only the minimum of these multi averages like that:

```
name  avg
---------
DP1   139
```

I tried this query but I get errors:

```
select  
    d.Dname, min(avg(e.salary)) as averagr_salary
from 
    Employee e, Departments d
where 
    d.Dnum = e.dno
group by 
    e.Dno, d.Dname
```

The error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Could you help me?

Comment: Wrap you `avg` aggregation into an outer `min` query.

Comment: Could you explain how

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
    Select tbl.Dname,min(averagr_salary) as  averagr_salary
from
(
select  d.Dname,avg(e.salary) as averagr_salary
from Employee e
inner join  Departments d
on  d.Dnum = e.dno
group by e.Dno,d.Dname
) as tbl
group by tbl.Dname
order by averagr_salary ASC limit 1;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhqJXYFy52xRtVBc97R1EL/1

For SQL Server:

```
Select top 1 tbl.Dname,min(averagr_salary) as  averagr_salary
from
(
select  d.Dname,avg(e.salary) as averagr_salary
from Employee e
inner join  Departments d
on  d.Dnum = e.dno
group by e.Dno,d.Dname
) as tbl
group by tbl.Dname
order by averagr_salary ASC;
```

Demo:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=303b9fab3403397b1df8ee79b9b216a6

Comment: The same result, it shows all averages not only the minimum average

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but, i'm using SQL server NOT (MYSQL), so there is syntax error when using (LIMIT), i'm sorry for this conflict, so i removed (MYSQL) Tag and edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle (**Updated**): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb4d5b2989e06f92bcb8c39742798ba4

Some stackoverflow UI controls are acting strangely.  Many of the normal controls, commenting, edit controls, etc, have not been functional for about 12 hours.

This solution is standard SQL and will work with SQL Server (recent versions); also notice, the logic works when there are multiple groups with an average which matches the minimum, not just one.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        d.Dname,
        AVG(e.salary) AS average_salary,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(e.salary)) AS n
    FROM 
        Employee e
    JOIN 
        Departments d ON d.Dnum = e.Dno
    GROUP BY 
        e.Dno, d.Dname
)
SELECT Dname, average_salary
FROM cte
WHERE n = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but, i'm using SQL server NOT (MYSQL), so there is syntax error when using (LIMIT), i'm sorry for this conflict, so i removed (MYSQL) Tag and edited my question